# how to deal with out of range values in dataset (RSSI values)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, localization, data-processing

I have dataset for indoor localization.the dataset contain columns for wireless access point about 520 column with the RSSI value for each one .the problem is each row of the dataset has values of one scan for a signals that can be captured by a device and the maximum number of wireless access point that can be captured about only 20 ( the signal can be from 0dbm which is when the device near the access point and minus 100dbm  when the device far from the access point but it can capture the signal) the rest of access points which are out of the range of the device scan they have been compensated with a default value of 100 positive.these value (100 dbm ) about 500 column in each row and have different columns when ever the location differ .the question is how to deal with them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option to deal with this issue, you could try to impute (change) the values that are out of range with a more reasonable value. There are several approaches you could take to do this:

- Replacing the out-of-range values with the mean or median of the in-range values
- Using linear interpolation to estimate the missing values based on the surrounding values

The choice will depend on the goal of your machine learning model and what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for answering . the model is for localization with different vlaues of RSSI about 520 point to give the location longitude and latitude and only about 20 of the values coming from these points are coming from the scan for the signal ,which has values between -100 to 0 (-100 for weak singal and 0 for very good singal)and when the points are out from the scan a defult value recorded in the dataset which is 100 .i can not just delete them .I apologize for the incomprehensible sentences. English is not my first language

Comment: @maryam The solution mentioned in this answer does not mean that you have to delete the rows with outlier RSSI values (>0). It means that you can change those outlier values to in-range values. For example: You can replace all values that are larger than 0 with 0. So the transformation would be value = 0 if value > 0. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/giantuji/UjiIndoorLoc/code?datasetId=572 that is the dataset i work with. I appreciate your answer, sir, but it is not possible to convert 100 to 0 simply because the reading that I get from an access point is equal to 0. This means that I am next to it.In the event that the device performing the scanning process cannot pick up the signal from an access point, a positive number 100 is substituted in the dataset.